# Understanding functions with list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

can someone explain me the last line of the code briefly about list comprehension

Tried to understand with different range values

```
def Function_1(x):
    return x*2

def Function_2(x):
    return x*4

empty_list = []
for i in range(16):
    empty_list.append(Function_1(Function_2(i)))

print(empty_list)

print([Function_1(x) for x in range(64) if x in [Function_2(j) for j in range(16)]])
```

Output:

```
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 112, 120]
[0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 112, 120]
```

Comment: the inner list comprehension is building a list for use in a filter operation. You could build that list before invoking the outer list comp. Also you could define it in its own function, which will give you more room and enhanced readability in the outer list comp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, what the last line does is,

`[(2 * x) for x in range(64)]`, which gives you a list of 64 numbers (multiplied by 2), and then we have a condition saying `if x in [(4 * j) for j in range(16)]`. It will check in the second list if the same number from the first lists exists and only those numbers will be considered in the final OP.

## OP function_1:

```
[(2 * x) for x in range(64)]
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98, 100, 102, 104, 106, 108, 110, 112, 114, 116, 118, 120, 122, 124, 126]
```

## OP function_2:

```
[(4 * j) for j in range(16)]
# [0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60]
```

Find if there are numbers from the first list in the second list and call them `x`, and return `2 * x`

```
print([x*2 for x in range(64) if x in [j*4 for j in range(16)]])
# [0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 72, 80, 88, 96, 104, 112, 120]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

The line

```
output = [function_1(x) for x in range(64) if x in [function_2(j) for j in range(16)]]
```

is equivalent to

```
output = []
y = [function_2(j) for j in range(16)]
for x in range(64):
    if x in y:
        output.append(function_1(x))
```

Comment: He wants an explanation. He can pretty much get the output himself using a for loop.

Comment: Maybe it is difficulty with understanding list comprehension syntax.